# I can't get rid of a string in a filter box in Joomla admin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

A few weeks ago I have noticed that a line of text appeared in the filter box of one the administration page of Joomla. It's something like 'destination=city:london'. I must have accidentally pasted this text into this box, I suppose
Since then, I can't get rid of it, so practically I cannot list any item on any admin page, because this taxt appears in the 'Filter' box initially, and if I delete it manually, it simply get back into the box.

How could I get rid of it?

I have alread cleared cache, but no success. Now this string occupies the 'filter' box of EVERY page of the admin area. I cannot work on my site any more.

Please help.

(I have posted this question at official Joomla forum weeks ago, but I didn't get reply so far)

Comment: **one the administration page of Joomla**....which page? for a component, plugin, default Joomla configuration?

Comment: Have you tried to click on clear button on filter area?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it disappeared after clearing the cache a few times. It took a day to work, it seems I was a bit impatient.